# Grails transient property not validating error?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have a domain class:

```
class Book {

    String id 
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    String title
    boolean acceptPolicy // defines if the user accepts the terms and privacy poicy
    String uploadImageId

    static transients = [ "acceptPolicy" ]  

    static constraints = {
            acceptPolicy( validator: { val, obj -> val == true} )
    }

}
```

I choose "acceptPolicy" as a field which should not be stored in the database. When I create a book object everything works find. The problem occurs when I update the book instance. Every time I try to save I get a validation error for the "acceptPolicy". This should not be the case because "acceptPolicy" is not stored in the database. I also tried to set the

```
acceptPolicy = true
```

in a hidden input field but still this problem occurs. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the validator and make it behave so that it only validates the acceptPolicy field when the entity is not yet persistent:

```
 acceptPolicy( validator: { val, obj -> obj.id || val } )
```